# Refresh items in DragSortListView

Tags: android, listview, sorting, drag, listviewitem

Am making a ListView with DragSortListView, so I can move the rows to reorder the list.
Well, I need to modify the behavior of the List. By default, the list can't be reordered (setDragEnabled = false) And when the user click on an item menu, only then the list could be reordered (setDragEnabled = true). 
The problem is that when I set my DragSortListView to setDragEnabled to true, only the items that **are not** currently on the screen are affected.

Eg: If my list has 10 items, but the screen can only show 6 (because of the size of the screen), then the other 4 items will be affected, but not the 6 that are currently on the screen.
Dont know if this is a "problem" of DragSortListView, or from the ListView in general.

So my question is: How can I update the data from all items inside a DragSortListView?

By now this is what I have

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.list_menu_item1:              
    ArrayList aL = new ArrayList();
    aL = (ArrayList) findViewWithTagRecursively(dslv,"_indicator");

    for(int i = 0; i < aL.size(); i++){
        dslv.setDragEnabled(true);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ImageView list_image = (ImageView)aL.get(i);
        //aL -> ArrayList with the items (views) in the list.
        list_image.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable
               (this.getResources().getIdentifier
                      ("drawable/delete_x",null,this.getPackageName())));
    }
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the loop, just call

```
dslv.setDragEnabled(true);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and in your Adapter's `getView()` set the drawable according to whether dragging is enabled or not. The `notifyDataSetChanged()` will cause `getView()` to be invoked for the list items as needed.